# ASP.NET MVC Route matching for child actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Does the approach of route matching for child actions differ from usual actions? In other words, do child actions have some autogenerated url to make matching similar to what is done for parent actions?

Comment: Why would you route a child action? They are not supposed to be called by an end user. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have no generl routes like {controller}/{action}/{id}. So all my routes are specific. So even for child actions I have to provide a route.

Comment: @frennky: Why not? Suppose you have parent action that returns a view with a list of items each displayed using a child action. User sees this list and edits individual item. Data gets Ajax posted to server and action returns the same partial as was used in parent view so client script can easily change item HTML in the list. **Perfectly valid scenario.** This is of course true when actions don't t have `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute on them. So they can be accesses directly. So they can be parent or child actions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No difference between parent or child action processing

Any action follows the same route definition you've set in your `Application_Start`. That means parent actions as well as child ones. If you gave specific routes for all actions in your application, then you must provide route definitions for your child actions as well.

### Avoid route processing by converting to `Html.RenderPartial()`

**If you can of course...** Child actions go through the same MVC processing as parent actions. It's of course different if you can change your `Html.RenderAction()` to `Html.RenderPartial()`. These don't go through the same processing hence are much much faster. Use `Html.RenderAction()` only when you can't do it any other way or doing it in other way would be to hackish (increased complexity of the view's model type etc).

### Actual `Html.RenderAction()` code excerpt

If you look at the code of `Html.RenderAction()` it calls into context processing to execute as if a request was made to the server:

```
// other code before this
RouteData routeData = CreateRouteData(data.Route, routeValues, data.DataTokens, htmlHelper.ViewContext);
HttpContextBase httpContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
RequestContext context = new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData);
ChildActionMvcHandler httpHandler = new ChildActionMvcHandler(context);
httpContext.Server.Execute(HttpHandlerUtil.WrapForServerExecute(httpHandler), textWriter, true);
```

We can se that it uses `ChildActionMvcHandler` handler which is inherited from `MvcHandler`, but is basically no different from it in terms of execution, because it doesn't have any new or changed functionality related to processing. So it executes MvcHandler's code basically.

### Outcome?

**Child actions execute as parent actions**, using the same routing definitions, controller action matching (action method selectors), filters etc.